# How to Stop reloading controller while using dynamic routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My intent is to

- stop reloading of the controller when using dynamic routes. eg: If I have a route defined as '/home/:param', and I am navigating from '/home/path1' to '/home/path2', the controller shoudnt get reloaded.

I tried to implement this by including templates using ng-include. Although it is not reloading the controller, the route url remains unchanged. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: have you set reloadOnSearch on the route?

Comment: @Donal, I havent set reloadOnSearch, its using the default values.

Comment: ok, try setting it to false - it should not reload the controller then.

Comment: @Donal, pls see my comment on your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set reloadOnSearch to false on the route - to prevent the controller from reloading when a query parameter or hash in the url changes. For more info, see [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider).

reloadOnSearch only relates to query parameters or hashes. So you would have to use query parameters for it to work. For example, your links would be something like this:

```
 <a href="#/test?id=1">Link 1</a>
 <a href="#/test?id=2">Link 2</a>
```

You can pick up the id using the `$location` service, like this:

```
function testCtrl($scope, $location) {
    alert("reloading controller with id: " + $location.search().id);
}
```

There is an updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/donal/2cz4nz3o/1/

Comment: As you suggested, I tried it with reloadOnSearch See this  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/13951/). But couldnt get it working so far. Is this even the current way to use reloadOnSearch?

Comment: @ibsenv unfortunately reloadOnSearch relates to search parameters (query strings).

Answer (score 1):

Picking up from Donal's answer, this is what I end up doing.

1. Set `reloadOnSearch=false` in the routeprovider.
2. Route Handing

   When getting routed via url,
   catch the param using `$location.search()` and load the corresponding template from within the controller.

   When loading a different template within the controller.
   trigger a function to change the template and update the url using 
   `$location.search('id',newTemplateId);`Since the reloadOnSearch is set to false, it does noting but changes the url.

Have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ibsenvalath/2cz4nz3o/2/)

Hope it helps somebody.

UPDATE : you may also want to set $routeUpdate when using reloadOnSearch. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19031250/angularjs-add-to-browser-history-without-page-reload-and-without-html5-pushstate).

Answer (score 0):

here's an [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14974271/can-you-change-a-path-without-reloading-the-controller-in-angularjs) for a similar question and some alternatives are given in the answers (alternatives to reloadOnSearch = false depending on your application)