# Location URL Parameter Misinterpretation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url

Issue originally was trying to set the parameters in the url correctly, however, this post solved it: [How can I set a query parameter in AngularJS without doing a route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17513093/how-can-i-set-a-query-parameter-in-angularjs-without-doing-a-route)

Then a new problem arose. When setting the url in the controller,

```
$scope.view = function(itemtmpl) {
    // change path and add parameter 'id' to the url
    $location.path('/itemtemplates/view/').search('id', itemtmpl.itemdefnid);
    // also tried with $routeProvider
    $location.url('/itemtemplates/view/' + itemtmpl.itemdefnid);
};
```

the item's ID is interpreted as separate arguments, not one number (the url will be used to make a REST call in a factory, so it has to be a single argument).

[image: Chrome Console Log]

[image]

That's the primary problem.

---

I thought there was a problem with my $location usage, so I went to the AngularJS docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

Still no luck.

$routeParams variable print out says that parameters are set accordingly.

Another idea I may need clarified is why my page's config will only recognize the $location.url when it's just appended to the end `view/1000`, not if it's a parameter `view/?1000` and still won't proceed if it has an id `view/?id=1000`

```
.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/itemtemplates/view/:id', {
    templateUrl: 'itemtemplates/add/main.tpl.html',
    controller: 'ViewCtrl'
  });
})
```

What could I be missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the controller for the URL I am trying to go to, the factory call was incorrect. I have to specify what argument I am trying to fulfill in the REST call, otherwise, the parameters are interpreted loosely. In my case, as a char array.

Was...

```
$scope.itemtmpl = item.query($routeParams.id);
```

Should have been...

```
$scope.itemtmpl = item.query({id: $routeParams.id});
```

This solves the first half of the problem. I am still trying to figure out how to use the url when parameters are set using `.search()`.