# Showing a username in the URL

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, routes

I have a single page Angular + bootstrap app where the user can enter their username (no password) into a text input and their user info will be displayed on screen.

I wish to make it so that when a user's info is displayed on the screen, the URL changes accordingly.

Eg: Entering this URL should directly into the browser: `localhost:3000/user1` should instantly open user1's info, without having to enter it into the textbox on my apps main screen.

Also, when you load the apps main screen, and enter `user2` into the text input and search, after the users info is loaded into the screen, the URL should change to `localhost:3000/user2` automatically.

You should know that my app is a single page app and does not already have angular routes introduced.

I just want to know what approach I should take. Thanks.

Comment: That's the question. What should I try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least 2 possible solutions you can implement:

Solution 1.

Create two api get methods, one isUserExist(), another getUserDetails().

As soon as you entered user name, click find, 
if isUserExist() returns true, redirect to user details page using $location.path('/:userId') where ":userId"=new_user_name

if not, show message "User does not exist".

Solution 2. (I would choose that)

Make your main url as localhost:3000/user?name=user1

Basically use param 'name'.

As soon as you clicked find and loaded new user details, 
you can dynamically update 'name' param like $location.search('name', 'user2')

set 'reloadOnSearch: false' in your $routeProvider.when() statement

```
    $routeProvider.when('/user', {
        templateUrl: 'some_user_template.html',
        controller: SomeUserCtrl,
        reloadOnSearch: false
    })
```

[How can I set a query parameter in AngularJS without doing a route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17513093/how-can-i-set-a-query-parameter-in-angularjs-without-doing-a-route)

You will get new user details loaded on the screen with updated url as

```
    localhost:3000/user?name=user2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! really appreciate answering this instead of down voting it to oblivion.